# Adjust the Space Between Two Jupyter Widgets

Tags: python, css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I'm trying to create a Jupyter Notebook to help some colleagues interactively access some data. I want to give them a bunch of widgets that allow them to use different criteria to filter the data.

Mainly it works beautifully, but I can't adjust the spacing between two widgets, and it's going to drive me nuts.

I've tried following the instructions [here](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-layout-attribute.), but the two buttons are always right next to each other.

```
class Dashboard(object):
    def __init__(self):
        item_layout = Layout(flex='1 1 auto',
                             width='auto')

        toggle = widgets.ToggleButtons(
            options=["Foo", "Bar"],
            value="Foo",
            description="Foobar:",
            disable=False,
            layout=item_layout,
        )

        check = widgets.Checkbox(
            value=True,
            description="Checked",
            disabled=False,
            layout=item_layout,
        )

        box_layout = Layout(display='flex',
                            flex_flow='row',
                            justify_content='space around',
                            width='500px',
                            button_layout='solid',
                            )

        buttons = widgets.Box(children=[
            widgets.interactive(self._set_foobar, foobar=toggle, layout=item_layout),
            widgets.interactive(self._set_checked, checked=check, layout=item_layout),
        ],
            layout=box_layout)

        display(buttons)

    def _set_foobar(self, foobar):
        self._foo = foobar == 'Foo'

    def _set_checked(self, checked):
        self._checked = bool(checked)
```

If I then open up a Jupyter notebook and do:

```
import dashboard
y = dashboard.Dashboard()
```

It produces:

[image]

If I don't make the widgets interactive i.e. `children=[toggle, check]` it works perfectly.

[image]

Is there a way that I can adjust the space between interactive widgets?

Comment: How about you create a [mcve]? We need to inspect the final result so we can see what's going on and tell you what to change to fix it. Can you reproduce the behavior here?

Comment: I've made an edit, but that's about as close to an MCVE as I can make. To see the results you need to save that code, then import and instantiate inside a notebook.

Comment: Well, I know CSS. I don't know Jupyter. I was hoping I could help. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4):

In Jupyter you can add classes to various widgets. If you have a button widget, add a class name to it using the `add_class()` function. Then, use the `display()` function to add some CSS.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
but_1 = widgets.Button(
     description = 'Button'
)
but_1.add_class("left-spacing-class")
display(HTML(
     "<style>.left-spacing-class {margin-left: 10px;}</style>"
))
display(but_1)
```